# Joomla : render custom fields in search results

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to display core custom fields in search results ? I can add custom fields in template override for article view like this :

```
<?php echo $this->item->jcfields[1]->value; ?>
```

It works fine for com_content but it doesn't display anything in search results (com_search).

Is there a way to render my custom fields in the search results ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template overwrite for the com search component like other overwrites by creating a 'html/com_content/com_search/search' folder in your current template.

[image: Dir structure]

In this you copy the content of /components/com_search/views/search/tmpl

You can find a description with examples here: https://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_Smart_Search_results_page 
This is targeted at Smart Search (com_finder), however you can follow this by replacing com_finder for com_search.

Then you customize and add the custom fields in the file: default_results.php in your overwrite file.

Please note that the custom fields are a string in the $result object

```
 ["jcfields"]=>
string(26) "Custom Field,Search123,1,2"
 echo "My fields: ".$result->jcfields;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for Smart Search in Joomla 4, here is the solution.

1. Create a template override of the file: components/com_finder/tmpl/search/default_result.php
2. At the start of the file (after line 20), add this code:

```
// Creates an array with all the CF of the current article.
$articleCustomFields = Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $this->result, true);

// Creates an associative array using the custom field id as a key.
$articleCustomFields = \Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper::pivot($articleCustomFields, 'id');
```

Then print the custom fields in the page:

```
<ul class="fields-container">
        <?php
        // We are using the custom fields with ids 10 and 3
        if (!empty($articleCustomFields[10]->value)) : ?>
            <li class="field-entry">
                <span class="field-label"><?= $articleCustomFields[10]->label ?>:</span>
                <span class="field-value"><?= $articleCustomFields[10]->value; ?></span>
            </li>
        <?php
        endif; ?>

        <?php
        if (!empty($articleCustomFields[3]->value)) : ?>
            <li class="field-entry">
                <span class="field-label"><?= $articleCustomFields[3]->label ?>:</span>
                <span class="field-value"><?= $articleCustomFields[3]->value; ?></span>
            </li>
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

If you are looking for a complete tutorial, please have a look at:
https://blue-coder.com/help/blog/adding-custom-fields-in-the-search-results

Comment: It is a great way to share your knowledge by posting an answer in the Stack Exchange Network.  May I ask, though, that you contribute to the Stack Exchange community that was deliberately created for sharing Joomla knowledge? It is perfectly legitimate and encouraged to ask a clear question and answer your own question.  I hope to see more from you on JSE.